# VB Style CD Embedding with .Net Framework

Tags: .net, vb6, installation, cd

In the old VB6 days it was possible to embed the runtime onto a cd and run the app automatically when the CD was popped in without having to run through an installation.

Is there anything available in .Net that mimics this?

Thanks
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

You will always need the dotNet framework on the target PC.

But after that, you can run from a CD, use simple XCopy deployment or a make a ClickOnce installation.

Comment: That's the problem though, we're not guaranteed that the .net framework will be there. This CD will be distributed to PCs and Macs alike. So essentially we've lost this capability with .net?

Comment: Yes, But I don't think your VB6 apps would have run on a Mac.